# How would I instrument an R2DBC for Spring Cloud Sleuth Zipkin?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, p6spy

For a normal data source I would do the following using P6Spy

```java
@Configuration
@Order(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class DataSourceBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof DataSource && !ScopedProxyUtils.isScopedTarget(beanName)) {
      log.debug("Decorating {} with P6Spy", bean);
      return new P6DataSource((DataSource) bean);
    } else {
      return bean;
    }
  }
}
```

But since R2BC uses a reactive DataSource how would I instrument that?

Answer (score 0):

P6Spy (and datasource-proxy) is for JDBC not for R2DBC.
R2DBC has its own proxy (formerly: datasource-proxy-r2dbc): https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-proxy